# How to disable css class suggestions in VS Code

Tags: css, class, visual-studio-code, intellisense

How I can disable css class suggestions that coming from a node_modules folder or from 3rd party css libraries. My VS Code suggestion window is polluted with them.
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DbvUZ.png)

Comment: [Try this](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/intellisense#_customizing-intellisense)